# I can't get my Nav Toggle button to work in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

i'm not sure why my navbar toggle button isnt working. Am I missing a class? Any help is much appreciated. I did some research but couldn't find a solution.

Thanks

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="WS.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Francois+One|Roboto+Mono|Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Wonder Stories Records</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-md navbar-light" style="">
    <div class="container"> <a class="navbar-brand text-primary" href="#">
          <a href="Index.html">  <img src="Images/Logo.png" width="150" ></a> 
      </a> <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right border-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar4">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon collapsed">
  
  </span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar4">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto pr-5">
          <li class="nav-item nav-pad"> <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item nav-pad"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Artists</a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item nav-pad"> <a class="nav-link" href="Releases.html">Releases</a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item nav-pad"> <a class="nav-link" href="About.html">Contact</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: i think you have not add Bootstrap css file and Jquery file. If you add these two it will work !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here's the [example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G28YFPAKOFB7) of your code: